# GridView (Binded to ObjectDataSource) not displaying fields in the selected fields zone in Fields Dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, objectdatasource

I have a Gridview that I bind to an ObjectDataSoure.

The ObjectDataSource uses a business object that calls a DAL method that returns DataTable with the query results.

Application works at run time ,**But at design time** there is a problem:
When I use the GridView's Tasks Wizard -> Edit Columns : **No fields appear** in the Selected fields text area(So I can't use the wizard to edit the columns).

DAL methods:

```
public override DataTable GetAllWorkers()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString)) {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("t_Workers_GetAllWorkers", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            return GetTable(cmd);
        } 

    }

    private DataTable GetTable(SqlCommand cmd)
    {

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        return dt;

    }
```

BLL Method :

```
public static DataTable GetAllWorkers()
    {
        return DataProvider.Instance().GetAllWorkers();
    }
```

ASPX web page :

```
       <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetAllWorkers" TypeName="BLL.BizImpl"></asp:ObjectDataSource>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" 
        EnableModelValidation="True" Height="156px" Width="270px">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Can someone please explain what is the cause for the problem ?

```
   Thanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that because you do not specifically declare your columns in your aspx Page you won't be able to see them in Wizard. At the moment your GridView is populated with data because the

```
AutoGenerateColumns
```

property defaults to true. You can turn the to false and define the columns yourself. You then have more control over what you want to display in them etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .When I tried to use SqlDataSource all the columns appeared in the  Selected fields text area at design time. So whey that not happning when I use ObjectDataSoure ? Is defining  the columns manually in the ASPX file my only option ?

Comment: Why not use the SqlDataSource then?

Comment: To be honest I'm not quite sure why it works with one and not the other. I would try it with defining the columns manually. If you were able to do it in SqlDataSource without defining the columns, where did it store the formatting information, did you notice if it was in the aspx?

Comment: Because it is not recommended .It imports  DAL logic to  the UI.

Comment: Yes when I used the SqlDataSource it automatically generated the columns info in the ASPX file.     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
                    SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
                    SortExpression="LastName" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

Comment: That's probably why you could see it then :). Also, if your don't want to use SqlDataSource have you considered LINQ? This will do the BLL and DAL for you.

Comment: No I have not considered  Link .But I will think about it .Thanks For your help :)